# Handle null values etc - in the builder class paradigm?

Tags: java, builder

I have a builder class for my custom type... and I don't always know for sure if a value is going to be present.

So lets say I am doing this :

```
MyCustomObject customObj = new MyCustomObject.MyCustomObjectBuilder()
    .setValueA(valueA)
    .setValueB(valueB)
    .setValueC(valueC)
    .setValueD(valueD)
    .setValueE(valueE)
    .build();
```

If any if my values are null - then this will obviously break, but I feel like have individual null checks right here in this block of code, negates the readability and convenience of a reusable builder class... is there a way to handle this?

Comment: why would it break? as long as `setValue...` doesn't return null, it shouldn't cause any issues. If you pass `null` arguments, then it just sets their values null.

Comment: Wy won't `build` call be able to verify that fields are coherent? Can' you use kind of `Optional`? Exception in setters?

Comment: @Strikegently - that is odd, I get a  null pointer exception when I send a null to it...

Answer (score 1):

`setValueX()` methods are invoked as instance methods of `MyCustomObjectBuilder`.
So even if you provide `null` as parameter, it doesn't matter.
As each one of these methods have to return `this` as last statement.
It is the way which the builder works.

For example :

```
public class MyCustomObject {

    private MyCustomObject(){}
    ...
    public static class MyCustomObjectBuilder {

       public MyCustomObjectBuilder setValueA(A a){
          ... // do assignment or anything

           // at the end
          return this;
       }

       public MyCustomObjectBuilder setValueB(B b){
          ... // do assignment or anything

           // at the end
          return this;
       }
       ...
    }
}
```

Of course, if inside `setValueX()` methods, you refer to a member of the parameter, you have first check that it is not `null` before.

Comment: so lets say I have .setValue(SomeOtherObject.getValueA)...

and SomeOtherObject is most definitely not null, but valueA is?

Comment: You mean that you want to pass as parameter in setValue() a builder method that provides a value ??

Comment: Yeah, basically, I want to be able to handle the situation in which that parameter would be null - at the minute I get a null pointer exception...

Comment: It is not a conventional way to interact with the builder. But you may achieve it by invoking  `.setValue(someOtherObject)` and by testing the no nullity of `someOtherObject` inside the method itself : `if (someOtherObject() != null)`. So, you can so access to `someOtherObject.getValueA())`